A thread-safe performant Money Transfer API in Java
This is a popular interview question. It is meant to be done within 30 minutes. The task is to implement a thread-safe performant Bank Account API that allows to transfer, deposit, withdraw and check balance.
I implement it as an Account class that stores a balance and performs synchronisation whenever a balance is updated. In order to prevent deadlocks while transferring, I order accounts by their IDs. I assume, there is a place storing accounts that keeps a single instance for each of the accounts (my code can be broken when I instantiate several instances of the same account).
Questions: I am interested to hear any feedback about the concurrency aspects of the solution as well as the general feedback. Is it thread safe? Are there possible concurrency issues? How can I improve the performance? Should I switch to using locks instead of synchronisation? Any other improvements? Would you expect anybody to write something like this in 30 minutes during an interview (what if there are also tests required)?
public final class Account implements Comparable<Account> {
    private final String id;
    private volatile BigDecimal balance;

    public Account(String id, BigDecimal balance) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(balance, "balance must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(id, "id must not be null");
        if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(balance) > 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Balance must not be negative");
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void deposit(BigDecimal value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value must not be null");
        if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(value) >= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be positive");
        synchronized (this) {
            this.balance = this.balance.add(value);
        }
    }

    public void withdraw(BigDecimal value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value must not be null");
        if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(value) >= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be positive");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (this.balance.compareTo(value) < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Insufficient balance");
            this.balance = this.balance.subtract(value);
        }
    }

    public void transfer(Account destination, BigDecimal value) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(destination, "to account must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(value, "value must not be null");
        if (this.equals(destination))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Destination account must not be the same account");
        if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(value) >= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be positive");
        if (this.balance.compareTo(value) < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Insufficient balance");
        var order = lockOrder(destination);
        synchronized (order[0]) {
            synchronized (order[1]) {
                if (this.balance.compareTo(value) < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Insufficient balance");
                this.balance = this.balance.subtract(value);
                destination.balance = destination.balance.add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private Account[] lockOrder(Account to) {
        if (this.compareTo(to) > 0) return new Account[]{this, to};
        else return new Account[]{to, this};
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return new BigDecimal(balance.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Account o) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(o, "the compared object must not be null");
        return this.id.compareTo(o.id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Account account = (Account) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, account.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
}

I am adding tests for basic operations. They are not comprehensive in terms of covering all checks and do not tests the concurrency aspects.
class AccountTest {

    @Test
    void shouldDeposit() {
        Account account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        account.deposit(new BigDecimal("456"));

        assertEquals(new BigDecimal("579"), account.getBalance());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToDepositGivenNegativeValue() {
        Account account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> account.deposit(new BigDecimal("-456"))
        );

        assertEquals("Value must be positive", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToDepositGivenZeroValue() {
        Account account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> account.deposit(BigDecimal.ZERO)
        );

        assertEquals("Value must be positive", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldWithdraw() {
        var account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("579"));

        account.withdraw(new BigDecimal("456"));

        assertEquals(new BigDecimal("123"), account.getBalance());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToWithdrawGivenInsufficientBalance() {
        var account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("579"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalStateException.class,
                () -> account.withdraw(new BigDecimal("600"))
        );

        assertEquals("Insufficient balance", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToWithdrawGivenNegativeValue() {
        Account account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> account.withdraw(new BigDecimal("-456"))
        );

        assertEquals("Value must be positive", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToWithdrawGivenZeroValue() {
        Account account = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> account.withdraw(BigDecimal.ZERO)
        );

        assertEquals("Value must be positive", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldTransfer() {
        var from = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));
        var to = new Account("b", new BigDecimal("200"));

        from.transfer(to, new BigDecimal("23"));

        assertEquals(new BigDecimal("100"), from.getBalance());
        assertEquals(new BigDecimal("223"), to.getBalance());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToTransferGivenInsufficientBalance() {
        var from = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));
        var to = new Account("b", new BigDecimal("200"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalStateException.class,
                () -> from.transfer(to, new BigDecimal("300"))
        );

        assertEquals("Insufficient balance", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToTransferGivenTheSameAccount() {
        var from = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> from.transfer(from, new BigDecimal("10"))
        );

        assertEquals("Destination account must not be the same account", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFailToTransferGivenNegativeValue() {
        var from = new Account("a", new BigDecimal("123"));
        var to = new Account("b", new BigDecimal("200"));

        var exception = assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> from.transfer(to, new BigDecimal("-10"))
        );

        assertEquals("Value must be positive", exception.getMessage());
    }
}


I voted to close this because unless you were actually presented with this question in an interview, it is hypothetical and we have no idea what the problem satement is looking for because there is actually nobody asking it. It makes very little sense to post answers to questions that we don't know the meaning of... I am of course open for discussion on whether this kind of questions are on topic for this site.

This is not code where you should be remotely worried about the performance. Maximize readability until you have a tested, proven bottleneck.
What happens when an external thread acquires and does not release the lock on an Account object?
Also, I do not believe transfer() works properly.
Account a = new Account(balance=5)
Account b = new Account(balance=12)

Thread 1: 
  start b.transfer(a, 2), 
  order = b, a, 
  yield()
Thread 2: b.transfer(a, 7)
  a.balance = 12
  b.balance = 5
Thread 1: 
  acquire lock on order[0], which is b, 
  yield()
Thread 2: 
  start b.transfer(a, 2), 
  order = a
  acquire lock on order[0], which is a,
-- deadlock --
Thread 1 holds the lock on b, thread 2 holds the lock on a, neither thread can progress.

If I make two different Account objects with the same id, they are treated as equal even if they have different balances. That's going to make a mess of collections.
It's preferable to use instanceof when overriding equals().
Also, your code formatting is pretty close to being a no-hire for me. Minimizing vertical space is not a virtue. Optional curly braces aren't.

Thank you for the review. Could you please elaborate on the deadlock issue? The lockOrder() method ensures two accounts are always returned in the same order (if it is [b,a] for the first call, it cannot be [a, b] for the second call). Both the threads would be acquiring "b" before "a". Am I missing anything?

The approach is flawed from the start. An Account does not perform money transfers. Accounts are just data objects. A money transfer is done by a service, that takes a Payment object and the payment object contains the necessary data (account identifiers for the debtor and creditor, the creditor name, transfer amount and currency, etc). So you should have started by implementing a PaymentService. And of course, the deposit and withdraw operations are completely different from transfer because they involve a physical component (the cash money) so they cannot be a part of the same API that handles transfers. You need to put them in a completely seprate service.
Even the problem statement says you're supposed to implement an API, not just data objects. Anyway, this interview question is a trick question. A bank API, even if you implement only one of the operations, is absolutely not a trivial thing that can be implemented in 30 minutes.
Of course, I may be biased since I work with actual consumer banking software. You're probably supposed to ask clarifying questions about what exactly are they looking for because as it is, the question is ridiculous.
